# Adding time series to date series

Tags: python, datetime

I'm fairly new to python. I have a dataframe with dates and series in different columns such as:

| Date        | Time       |

| 2022-05-13  | 17:01:56   |

I would like to ad the two together and get the following:

| DateTime            |
| 2022-05-13 17:01:56 |

What is the most intuitive way of doing this? I tried to ad them together using pd.to_datetime but it did not work.

Regards,
Holmbrero

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Date': ['2022-05-13'],
        'Time': ['17:01:56']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df = df.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
             DateTime
0 2022-05-13 17:01:56
```

You could also use a datetime object which might be useful for incrementing and or formatting:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2022-05-13 17:01:56"
formatted_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```